# Scheme in the header: logo , slogan, image, etc, Should I use containers or not?

Tags: css

I want to create a schema like this:

[image]

I'm wondering if it is better create a div container for logo and slogan or not.. 
I'm wondering also if it is better create a div container for telephone icon, phone1, phone2 and facebook button or not..

Someone told me that is not necessary, and in that way I could save some bits..

What is your opinion? containers or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

honestly this is the best solution i may think of, it has balance between minimum `css` and `html` coding, http://jsfiddle.net/fkrQa/.
hope this helps